# What conditions are required to figure out that zabbix agent service become unavailable?

Tags: zabbix

I want to "remove host" in case of zabbix agent become not available during more than 10 minutes.

I created a new action as following:
Conditions: 
- `Uptime/Downtime >=600`
- `Discovery status = Down`
- `service type = Zabbix agent`

Operation:
remove host

In order to check it I stopped the zabbix agent in host side, but the host was not removed.

My question is whether `Uptime/Downtime` and `Discovery status` in the conditions are affected only from zabbix agent service? or it can be affected also from others services which are not included in the conditions (i.e ICMP ping).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The **Uptime/Downtime** and **Discovery status** parameters defined are only affected by the status of the Zabbix Agent as well as SNMP agent if used for the Discovery.

You can also refer the below link for the same:

**https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/auto-discovery**

Comment: First thank you. 
So if the discovering of specific host made by both ICMP and zabix agent services, and I created the following conditions: Uptime/Downtime >=600  and Discovery status = Down and service type = Zabbix agent
Even the zabbix agent will be down more then 600 minutes but the ICMP will be active the conditions will be false?
I thought that if I add the service type as a condition, the rest of the conditions are only related to it (zabbix agent).